# Color model name

Tags: css, colors, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning bootstrap from twitter, I want to do some color changes, and I got this color code: `#08c`

I want to know if it represent `#0088cc` (and same way for other variations?)

and how is it called so I can find some online color palette.

I thank your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `#08c` is equivalent to `#0088cc`.

Not all colors have names.  This one in particular does not.

For a list of all named colors defined in css3 see [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/)

From the spec

> The format of an RGB value in hexadecimal notation is a ‘#’
>   immediately followed by either three or six hexadecimal characters.
>   The three-digit RGB notation (#rgb) is converted into six-digit form
>   (#rrggbb) by replicating digits, not by adding zeros. For example,
>    #fb0 expands to #ffbb00. This ensures that white (#ffffff) can be specified with the short notation (#fff) and removes any dependencies
>   on the color depth of the display.

Answer (score -1):

I use this site

http://www.2createawebsite.com/build/hex-colors.html

to generate color codes for my colors. #08c is not a full representation but it could mean #00008c.